# Animal Death before the fall?

Tags: isaiah

I hear so many different responses to this. Just wanted to see if anyone could clear up how I put this. We have old Earth vs New Earth Christians. I myself fall on the Old Earth View. John Lennox and Frank Turek clear that up pretty well. This aligns with what we see in science etc. Young Earth views would have to take the complete opposite direction of what modern science says which I find to be extremely hard? They can’t possibly be wrong on everything? I mean we date trees older than Young Earth views. Could it all be a lie? Maybe. Is there better answer maybe it’s how we interpret Genesis.. It’s likely. Now if I take the Old Earth view. I would have to take animal death prior to the fall of man. My question is why? Why would god let things die and be called “good” another question would be why would god not call it “perfect” to begin with? We have scripture such as Romans that people use to explain death not coming until the fall but the context behind this is “spiritual” death of man. Not creation. But we do see also in scripture where creation groans… clearly indicating because of Sin. We have Isaiah talking about a “New Creation” where there is complete harmony between all creation. But that’s my point… is this talking about the pre sin creation?! Or a totally “New Creation” the only valid response I can come up with is. Is it possible that god created and designed the first earth in a way with a “Life cycle” before the fall. Knowing Adam would already sin. So when man sinned… nature was already in a cycle.. because I also hear this… without the natural cycle of animal life we would be over crowded and some species wouldn’t survive. This is the only thing I can come up with to Justify death before humans. God made a world ready for man’s fall. The “New Creation” in Isaiah is perfect harmony and Peace with all creation which was gods intention in the first place. Other wise?! How do we explain death before humans on earth? Do I believe science knows everything? No. But I find it extremely difficult to be a young Earth creationist. If we are wrong about things we find in the fossils and ages of trees etc… what are we right in? Forensic science? Math? Etc… seems like nothing.

Comment: Welcome to BH. Your question brings up important Bible issues but to make it fit this site do read the tour [below, left] and see if you can focus on the meaning of a particular Scripture. "Scientific Creationism" and "Biblical Creationism" both books by Dr H Morris are, I think, Bible based and relevant to issues you mention.

Comment: What needs to be borne in mind is that scientists are not Christians, they are part of a world which rejects God. They actively seek to deny the record of God's creation. There is a vast amount of speculation and supposition that is labelled as 'fact' when it is nothing of the kind. I believe the record of God's word and I find nothing that, once it is properly investigated, contradicts it. I reiterate the suggestion of @C.Stroud and recommend the book 'The Genesis Flood' by Morris and Whitcombe.

Comment: @Nigel You say, "scientists are not Christians", how about "many scientists are not Christians"?  Ken Ham and others who write about the Bible and science are highly qualified in science.

Comment: @Nigel Morris was a professor of applied science at Southern Illinois University.

Comment: This question does not bring a specific Bible verse forward as context.  It also presupposes that Scripture must agree with Atheistic science religion.  Evolution is not science, but a false religion that was derived to allow a belief in a godless creation.  Moreover, carbon dating formulas are manipulated to give the millions & billions of years that evolution religion requires.  It takes blind faith to believe in evolution.  Please look at all of the truth published at ApologeticsPress.org that de-bunks the "scientism" of old earth.

Comment: The obvious answer is God did not let animals die before the fall and the "young earth" is the correct understanding. Old earth is a product of the assumption calculations can be made using current observations and projected back in time to the beginning. The correct view is created objects have the **appearance** of age, if the standard used is based on current observations. Example, a garden with tree bearing fruit appears to be many years old; it was at most 3 days old.

Comment: If you want a more scientific explanation relativity states observers with different reference points will get different measurements of space and time. Despite being different, both are correct. God's point of reference is not the same as man's. Therefore, science demands God's measurements **must** be different from man's. Man may object to the magnitude of the difference, but the fact there is a difference is expected. So man's claim God's measurements are wrong based on the lack of agreement is contrary to the theory of relativity. It is an objectively false position.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend not to attempt to reconcile Genesis with the sciences. The Bible doesn’t change, but science changes constantly.

For example, for many years, people scoffed at Genesis where it said that God created light before creating the sun and stars. Now, the scientific consensus is that light did appear in the universe before the stars formed.

Interpretive possibilities of the appearance of death in Genesis include

1. There was no death at all before the fall—neither plants, animals, nor microbes. Even skin cells didn’t die.
2. There was no animal death before the fall.
3. There was no animal predation before the fall. All animals and humans ate plants.
4. There was only no *human* death before the fall.

Genesis 1:29,30 ESV reads

> And God said, “Behold, I have given you every plant yielding seed that
> is on the face of all the earth, and every tree with seed in its
> fruit. You shall have them for food. And to every beast of the earth
> and to every bird of the heavens and to everything that creeps on the
> earth, everything that has the breath of life, I have given every
> green plant for food.” And it was so.

This seems to favor at least interpretation 3 above, but doesn’t preclude the possibility of interpretation 2. However, the fact that God was able to warn Adam and Eve that eating one fruit would result in their deaths presupposes that they knew what death was.

Also, notice that God clothed Adam and Eve with animal skins after the fall. This required the death of an animal, perhaps a sheep.

Carbon-14 dating and tree ring dating also have problems (requiring "calibration") and includes assumptions of unlikely steady-state conditions on earth over long periods of time. Dating methods used on the “stretchy material” found in dinosaur bones produce far *younger* results than expected. Various alternative dating methods also produce divergent results, so we end up with approximations.
As a result, I hold *some* of my Biblical interpretations and *all* of my science understandings loosely.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree with science changing constantly. But I also believe Science helps us reveal scripture as well. Such as the Big Bang. It shows that Time, Space, Matter had a beginning. Everything that has a beginning must have a cause. That cause is God. A Spaceless, Timeless, Immaterial, powerful being. I think my issue comes from the fact that (Day) means 5 different things in Genesis. In day 7 there was no morning and evening. It never says it ended. Or in the first verse. In the beginning God created the heavens and the Earth. When was the beginning?

Comment: Yes, I find this fascinating as well! According to Einstein, space and time are inseparable as "spacetime."  You can't have one without the other. So, I read "In the beginning" as God creating spacetime from outside of space and time. Then, just as a meter stick is necessary as a standard to measure distance, one needs regular periodicity to measure time. Without the earth orbiting the sun, we have no familiar periodicity (to establish hours, etc.) except for the undefined light-dark cycles in Genesis created by God. God's periodicity also allows for God's seventh day to still be in progress.